# How create bouncycastle CmsSignedData with device like token, smart card?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

i have a token (security device)
and can :
read Certificate 
Sign data (no private key available)

but all CmsSignedDataGenerator need private key

i have
public key, certificate, signature (signed content with rsa_sha_1)

how generate CmsSignedData without private key (only signature, public key, certificate)?
any sample in c#? that can help me?

Comment: you have to use the private key to sign. 

what are you trying to do? verify a signature? sign raw data?

Comment: read a device using pcks11 and sign data as der format pkcs 7 message